# What does "in it" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does "in it" mean in football (soccer) context?

> **GOAL! Everton 1-2 Burnley (Calvert-Lewin 32)**

> He’ll be chewing a little less maniacally now! Davies, partly to blame for the opening goal, whips a cross in from the right. It’s an absolute beauty, right on the head of Calvert-Lewin, who powers past Pope from close range. Everton are back **in it**

Comment: It is sometimes **very difficult** to picture the plays without the footage. Anyway, here this means: They now have a chance to equalize or even win: They are back in the game.

Answer (score 1):

Everton are back in it = Everton are back in **the game**.

The implication is that Everton have been losing/playing poorly or without enthusiasm/success and now their spirits have been raised by their attack and they are playing as if they can win.